# zip directory in iphone

Tags: iphone, directory, zip

Is it possible to zip the directory in iPhone programmatically?
(I am not asking about the files)

I tries with  zlib.
When getting the data of a directory it return 0

I tried with

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dir];
```

Comment: Please add the code on how you got the directory.

Comment: use zipArchive code (minizip) and send path of your data.

Comment: code fore getting the directory is //hardcoded

     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/MyDirectory"];

Comment: i tried with zipArchive, result is still the same. It works well with the individual files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zlib sounds like a good choice. You can't just pass a directory as a parameter, though; you have to iterate over each file in the directory.

See this example of compressing a directory's files:

http://wdlindmeier.com/blog/blog/posts/compressing_directory_contents_on_the_iphone_with_zlib